# Weekly Status report application

Tags: ajax, web-services, ms-access, infopath

I want to create a weekly status report application in which users can append to a status report throughout the week and then at the end of the week, they can submit the report to the manager. I want a separate interface for the manager so that they can view reports for several different users. Preferably I would like the application to be web based.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to approach this.

I don't have much experience with web application development, but I am willing to learn and write this from scratch if this is the best approach.
If I were to write this from scratch, does anyone have a suggestion on which language to use ?  I also do have access to Microsoft Infopath and Microsoft Access, but I want the application to be available online rather than a desktop application.

Also, I am not sure if I should store the reports in a database or on a file system. There will probably be 16 people sending in a status report every single week. I want the manager to be able to query the reports quickly but I i'm not sure if it is good to store whole files in a database.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You mention MS Access so you might like to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402351.aspx and http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5970, alternatively, consider a different database. You might also like to add a few notes on the expected number of users.

Comment: Hey Remou, there will be around 17 users. I do have access to a sharepoint server, but I am not sure storing 16 reports each week will take up too much space on the server

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have web development experience, then the road is a bit long for developing such an application. All you need to is to store the reports on a shared location either on the web or LAN or Sharepoint. GoogleDocs or ZOHO and other services may provide very close functionality. Each worker would manage his/her own documents and permissions could be set such that the manager could read anyone's data. No need to use a database to store the reports.